My Hyper-V virtual machine can't boot anymore due to errors
I created a VM last week and had it running smoothly and doing exactly what I needed. Unfortunately this week whenever I try and start my VM I get an error code that says "The session was disconnected. If you want to continue, try to connect again. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator" The other error that shows up says "Video remoting was disconnected". I've found some solutions online, but unfortunately they aren't exactly what I need. The trick to get around this is turning off Enhanced Session Mode, but I   NEED Enhanced Session Mode turned on. I've restarted my computer and virtual machines numerous times, I've changed the port number, I've created a new virtual machine and get the same exact error messages. Does anybody know a workaround for this? I also have a password on my VM account, so that also isn't the issue. I cannot seem to figure out a workaround for this. The VM is Windows 10.

How are you connecting to the VM? How did you change the port number? WHY did you change the port number? You are saying the VM isn't booting, but none of the rest of the post indicates a boot issue, just a remote connection issue. What are the specs/settings of the host computer?

I'm connecting to the VM using Hyper-V Manager. I changed the port number using Regedit and going to (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization) and double clicking ListenerPort. The reason I changed it was because I was trying to find solutions to the problem listed on here and was following along with instructions online. Here is the link to the video instructions I was following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDmh-KQEN_U&ab_channel=NetworkingBit). The host computer is a W10 Version 22H2 machine. Not sure what other specs you'd want/need.
